# Data-separation in a Symfony Multi-tenant app using Doctrine

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, multi-tenant

I am trying to implement a multi-tenant application, that is
- data of all clients in a single database
- each shared table has a `tenant_id` field to separate data

I wish to achieve data separation by adding `where('tenant_id = ', $user->getTenantID())` {pseudoc-code}
to all SELECT queries
I could not find any solution up-front, but here are possible approaches I am considering.
1) crude approach:
customizing all `fetchAll` and `fetchOne` functions in every class (I will go mad!)
2) using listeners:
possibly coding for the `preDqlSelect` event and adding the 'where' to all queries
3) override `buildQuery`(): could not find an example of this for front-end
4) implement `contentformfilter`: again need a pointer

Would appreciate if someone could validate these & comment on efficieny, suitability.
Also, if anyone has achieved multitenancy using another strategy, pl share. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have published the sfMultiTenantPlugin, find it here:
http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfMultiTenantPlugin

Comment: Is the link broken now?

Answer (score 2):

I'm working out a solution using Doctrine Record Listeners by coding the preDqlSelect event. I think this is the best & easiest way to do things in a generic way, rather than having to modify every Table class and writing Tenant aware queries. With listeners, multi-tenancy will be completely transparent to developers.

Thanks for participating.

Answer (score 1):

I belive that the more feasible and secure way is to create a new function to retrieve a tenant aware query, this is an example... Replace MyModel with the name of your table:

```
// lib/model/doctrine/MyModelTable.class.php
class MyModelTable extends Doctrine_Table
{
  public function createTenantAwareQuery($userId)
  {
    $q = $this->createQuery('m')
      ->where('tenant_id = ', $userId);
    return $q;
  }
}
```

Then to consume this new function just call:

```
$myVar = Doctrine_Core::getTable('MyModel')->createTenantAwareQuery()
  ->where('something = ', $value);
```

In this way you create a "Tenant Aware query" when needed... you just use this function when needed... Even in the admin generator there is a way in the configuration file to override the default query method:

```
# apps/backend/modules/(module)/config/generator.yml
config:
  list:
    table_method: retrieveTenantAwareResult
```

The only thing left is to create this method.

Hope this answer works for you =)

Comment: I will go crazy adding this for each & every query/table!

Comment: passing the user_id around is also painful. So far the plugin has worked really well for me